# How to handle ScriptManager AddHistoryPoint with empty parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser-history, scriptmanager

I have a ScriptManager with EnableHistory set to "True". I use AddHistoryPoint method to save filter terms for some filter on a page.

For example:

```
this.ScriptManager.AddHistoryPoint("filterterm", "somevalue");
```

So the address bar in a browser shows something like

```
.../mypage.aspx?id=1#&&filterterm=somevalue
```

It works perfectly, except when I remove all filters and so I need to save a history point without a key (in other words with string.Empty key)

When this happens, the address bar in a browser shows:

```
.../mypage.aspx?id=1#
```

Notice the empty anchor. It makes the scroll position of the page be reset to the top. This is very annoying.

Do you know any approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I used not the best solution but at least it works. I've added a dummy parameter, which is added when filter terms are added. And when all filter terms are removed the dummy parameter will be left in the URL, so the scroll position won't be reset.

```
this.ScriptManager.AddHistoryPoint("filter", "1");
```

Note: the dummy parameter should be ignored when parameterers are parsed.